# r Shiny - looping through or amending an array that takes UI

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking for some help on running simulations with parameters taken from user input.

The goal is 1) to make a null array and populate it zeros, with dimensions based on user inputs, 2)set the first row with starting values (all the same starting value) from UI, 3)run simulations and fill the array and then plot results.

I have all of these functions working well in R, but running them with Shiny has proved more difficult. Here is the server code to give an idea of what I want:

```
library(reshape)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  X <- reactive({
    array(0,dim=c(500,input$nsim))

    })

  X[1,]<-rep(input$p,input$nsim)

  for(j in 1:N.sim){
   for(i in 2:N.gen){
      p.i = rbinom(1,N.chrom,prob=1-X[i-1,j])/N.chrom
      meanfit <-p.i^2*w.aa+2*p.i*(1-p.i)*w.ab+(1-p.i)^2*w.bb
      X[i,j] =1-(p.i^2*w.aa/meanfit+p.i*(1-p.i)*w.ab/meanfit)
    }  
  }


  output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(X) #plot the results of the simulations (loops).

  })    
}

)
```

I am able to make the array X based on ui passed dimensions, but then I can't alter the array (X) any further outside of the reactivity call. How can I initiate the array and then amend the first row (starting values)? And ultimately, then how do I also run loops over the array? DO I need to have all three steps outlined above in one reactivity call?

I usually modify arrays or vectors on separate lines   e.g:
`X<-array(0,dim=c(500,input$nsim))
    X[1,]<-rep(input$p,input$nsim)`'

Perhaps this is sloppy code, and  clearly this isn't working with Shiny.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

LP

Answer (score 0):

A `reactive` expression is basically a bunch of commands that are executed when a value of the user inputs from which it depends changes value. It's pretty much like a function. It is called as a function (without arguments) and it returns the last evaluated command. For first thing, you should use two different names for the reactive expression and the array you want to build. For instance, let's call the reactive expression `createArray`, while `X` is your array. It should be clear that you need to create the array when a user changes input and then call the result inside, for instance, a `renderPlot`. Here is what may work:

```
  shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  createArray <- reactive({
    X<-array(0,dim=c(500,input$nsim))
    X[1,]<-rep(input$p,input$nsim)

    for(j in 1:N.sim){
       for(i in 2:N.gen){
          p.i = rbinom(1,N.chrom,prob=1-X[i-1,j])/N.chrom
          meanfit <-p.i^2*w.aa+2*p.i*(1-p.i)*w.ab+(1-p.i)^2*w.bb
          X[i,j] =1-(p.i^2*w.aa/meanfit+p.i*(1-p.i)*w.ab/meanfit)
       }  
    }
   X 
   })

   output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ourArray<-createArray() 
      plot(ourArray) #plot the results of the simulations (loops).
   })    
   })
```

Comment: Thanks Nicola. That helps a lot. I can't seem to get it to plot though...  When running ggplot after `ourArray<-createArray()` in `renderPlot` i get the error `attempt to a apply non-function`. ggplot code is `ggplot(ourArray, aes(x = rep(c(1:500), as.numeric(input$nsim)), y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()`.   What could be causing the non function error?